# Cast Icon can be seen in AppBase theme but not in App.compat Theme

Tags: android, google-cast

I have been trying learning google cast from last couple of days now. I'm learning Android Sender Development. I tried running Sample Android Sample app,i.e., https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-android. As the Readme says, I've checked out the code & tried running it on Android Studio. At First, I couldn't see cast icon in the preview section of Android Studio. After, changing the theme in Preview from Base.Theme.AppCompat to AppTheme I could see Cast Icon(Actually, its just a title saying "Play on..") in preview but when I run it on my phone I couldn't see this icon.So, I tried changing the theme in AndroidManifest file. Currently, in AndroidManifest  theme is Theme.Appcompat `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` . When I change it to style/AppTheme, the app crashes on Mobile. What can be done here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ActionBarActivity, then your theme should inherit from the Theme.AppCompat. As for not seeing the cast icon, what App ID are you using? What receiver are you using? Most likely what you are experiencing is because you either have not set up the App Id correctly in the app, or have not registered your chromecast for your app id or something along those lines. Provide more information so you can get more specific help.

Comment: As for inheriting from Theme.Appcompat, that was my first go. But, as I said earlier, I coudn't see cast icon. Also, I'm a little bit unsure on how the reciever thing works. I tried using the App Id that was already there in the code but it didn't work. So I tried registering my App with cast.google.com & got an AppId.

Comment: Also I'm using my TV as cast device (status is "Ready for testing") but I'm not sure on how to add the reciever.html in TV. I don't want to use chromecast here, but I couldn't find any documentation that describes how to setuo reciever files in TV. FYI: I have a samsung smart TV with basic cast features like casting youtube, netflix, etc

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "I don't want to use chromecast here". Do you have a chromecast and is it connected to your TV's HDMI or not?

Comment: I don't have chromecast but I can cast Youtube, Netflix, etc on my TV. So, I'm assuming I can cast my android app without using chromecast.

Comment: No you can't. You are using Smart TV feature of your Samsung TV. To use the Cast SDK, you need to use a Cast device, which is either a Chromecast or an Android TV.

Comment: So, just for my understanding, do I have to use any other SDK for casting my application ? Does cast SDK work only for chromecast? Also, I came across this game  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rolocule.motiontennis&hl=en which do not use Chromecast but still casts the game on TV. So I was wondering there must be a way to achieve this without using chromecast. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I suggest you go to https://developers.google.com/cast/ and make yourself familiar with the Google Cast if that is what you want to accomplish.